# Why does sys.getsizeof fail on a pandas series or data frame when they hold a type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sizeof

Python getsizeof fails on a series which holds a type as data , I have function in which I need to calculate the size of any given argument which I do with getsizeof. But this is an issue as  getsizeof fails unexpectedly for these kind of dataframes. Is there a way to avoid this failure in `getSizeof`

```
import sys
df=pd.Series(str)

sys.getsizeof(df)
```

```
TypeError: descriptor '__sizeof__' of 'str' object needs an argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Pandas bug.

Pandas makes the unusual decision of trying to compute a "deep" sizeof, including all element sizes, rather than just the memory consumption directly attributable to the `Series` instance itself. The `__sizeof__` implementation for a `Series` instance eventually hits a [loop](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/75c1b9630aa089f66f24723a5b95a0d388773d6b/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L145) that tries to call `__sizeof__` on the elements:

```
for i in range(n):
    size += arr[i].__sizeof__()
return size
```

but calling `__sizeof__` like this is incorrect. It should really call `sys.getsizeof(arr[i])`.

Calling `__sizeof__` like this is wrong for two reasons: first, as you've seen, it fails when an element is a type object, because `str.__sizeof__` is the unbound method for computing the size of a string, not the method for computing the size of the `str` type object itself. Second, `sys.getsizeof` adds corrections for GC metadata that `__sizeof__` doesn't account for.

Comment: So how should sizeof be called for series or dataframes?

Comment: @ArunJose: You're calling it correctly. Pandas *itself* is using `__sizeof__` incorrectly internally. That's not your fault.

Comment: filed an issue in github https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51858

Answer (score 2):

I solved it at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51858.
Upgrade pandas and you should be able to run the same code with no problem:

```py
import sys
df=pd.Series(str)
sys.getsizeof(df)
```